# Trying to sanitize input with isNaN method, but it crashes the while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, crash, jsfiddle

I am attempting to code for a project that requires me to prompt the user to input a number. I have the code set up so it accepts only numbers and operates on them, but it doesn't sanitize the input until the end. I tried using an inNaN method and a while loop to keep the code going until the user enters a real number, but when it identifies NaN, it crashes. Here's my code below:

```
  var userMin = Number(prompt("Name a minimum number to begin your range. 
  Only numbers, please.")); //This is the prompt that asks for the number
  var repuserMin = true; //This is the beginning of the while loop
  while (repuserMin){
  if (isNaN(userMin)) {
  repuserMin = true; //Where the if statement glitches, JSFiddle crashes at this point
  } else {repuserMin = false;}}
```

Comment: if isNaN(userMin) is true ... repuserMin = true .... so while(repuserMin) will run forever until the browser tells you that there's an issue ... `userMin` never changes within that while loop, so once it's NaN it'll always stay NaN - you'll need to prompt for a new value inside the while loop if the input value is `NaN`

Comment: `var userMin;
while (true) {
    userMin = Number(prompt("...."));
    if (!isNaN(userMin)) break;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will crash because you are trying to run a infinite while loop there.

You need to take the input from the user every time inside the loop.

```js
var repuserMin = true; //This is the beginning of the while loop
var userMin;
while (repuserMin) {
  userMin = Number(prompt("Name a minimum number to begin your range. Only numbers, please.")); //This is the prompt that asks for the number
  if (isNaN(userMin)) {
    repuserMin = true; //Where the if statement glitches, JSFiddle crashes at this point
  } else {
    repuserMin = false;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

You need to handle the case where the user will not enter anything.
`isNaN('') --> false`

```js
while (true) {
  var userMin = Number(prompt("Name a minimum number to begin your range. Only numbers, please.")); //This is the prompt that asks for the number  
  if (!isNaN(userMin) && userMin) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `userMin` **inside** of the loop, by prompting the user to update the value if their entry is not a number:

```js
var userMin = Number(prompt("Name a minimum number to begin your range. Only numbers, please.")); //This is the prompt that asks for the number

var repuserMin = true; // Trigger the loop by default

while (repuserMin) {
  if (isNaN(userMin)) {
    userMin = Number(prompt("Name a minimum number to begin your range. Only numbers, please."));
  } else {
    repuserMin = false; // Break out of the loop
    console.log('Number was entered');
  }
}
```